# SQL - Using 1 foreign key to concatenate and join two columns from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key (say, FK_Id of an integer type) in the "main" table of my database. The FK_Id refences a "Users" table, which has columns for FirstName and LastName.

What SQL command can I run to join the foreign key in the main table to the "Users" table, while at the same time concatenating the FirstName and LastName columns into one full name?

More context:

```
CREATE TABLE main(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,    
    FK_Id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(FK_Id) REFERENCES Users(Id)
);
```

(Note: In reality, there are more columns in the main table, but I am excluding them for simplicity).

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,    
    FirstName TEXT,
    LastName TEXT
);
```

Ideally, I want a result where the "main" table, in the FK_Id column, now contains FirstName + " " + LastName from the Users table.

I know how to concatenate, and I know how to join one foreign key to *one* column... my problem is 1) concatenating in the same call as the join (if possible)
2) using the one foreign key to reference / concat *two* columns (FirstName and LastName)

Thanks.

Comment: The foreign key FK_Id references the id of Users and not the other 2 columns . It's a simple join.

Comment: Oh, so if I call "join" by FK_Id on Users, it will gather both columns of information (first and last)?

Comment: It will match each row of the 1st table to a row of the 2nd table and you can access all columns of any of the 2 tables.

Answer (score -1):

select a.Id, b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName
from main a join Users b on a.FK_id = b.Id

first name and last name are not related to the join key at all.